# How can i route all subdomains to www in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, subdomain

I have subdomains like emr.example.com ksc.example.com but i want to redirect all subdomains to www domain in routes.rb I tried that solution but it didnt worked https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21582 how can i fix that I'm using ruby 2.7.2 Rails 6.1

Comment: Your routes are for internal routes of your application, not for creating external links

Comment: Try `link_to "your link",  "https://google.com"`

Comment: Its not what i want, if user enters xyz.example.com route redirect to automatically www.example.com

Comment: what hasn't worked exactly in the solution you tried ? is it not redirecting at all or redirecting to a wrong place or what?

Comment: I added the code in the issue Its redirecting wrong place if i go to xyz.example.com it redirects www.xyz.example.com same in the issue i need to redirect just www.example.com @JoelBlum

Comment: even i added config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0 in development.rb

Comment: This is something you would do in Apache or NGinx before the request hits your rails application.